# is there an eval in ML?

Tags: ocaml, eval, ml, polyml

is there a eval function in ML?

Answer (score 1):

ML is really just a dialect, but no ML implementation that I've used (OCaml, F#) has eval as far as I know.  This makes sense as ML uses strict typing (the types are known at compile time).  Eval would break that guarantee.

However I did find an implementation of eval in OCaml that apparently uses code from the toplevel:

http://thelackthereof.org/OCaml_Eval

Comment: I believe the term you want is "static typing"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have some sort of eval in F#, but the code to be evaluated has to be quoted.

```
#r"FSharp.PowerPack.dll"
#r"FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"
(* load the PowerPack *)
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.QuotationEvaluation
let x = <@@ 8*11 @@>
x.EvalUntyped() // = 88
```

More about code quotations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least SML/NJ and Poly/ML can do this: code is compiled at run-time and added to the environment.

For Poly/ML there is a worked example here: [ML REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555790/does-sml-poly-have-a-cl-like-repl)

Poly/ML can do more things like that, e.g. managing the ML environment under program control.  It also supports source-level debugging, with arbitrary evaluation at breakpoints.