# PolyML runtime eval

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, eval, polyml

I am currently using PolyML 5.5.2, and trying to create a runtime compiler function that takes a string and runs it.

The desired function should be like

fun eval string -> unit

when input

> >eval "val a=1;";
>
> val a = 1: int

I have done some research that in old version there is a function like PolyML.compilerEx but it seems there is no such thing in PolyML 5.5.2.

Many thanks to all.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555790/does-sml-poly-have-a-cl-like-repl

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PolyML.compiler](http://www.polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLStructure.html#compiler).  The documentation is closer to the forthcoming 5.6 release but it should work fine with 5.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

You will want something along the lines of

```
PolyML.compiler(infn,
                [PolyML.Compiler.CPErrorMessageProc record_error,
                 PolyML.Compiler.CPOutStream obufPush]) ()
```

where `infn` is the function that gives the compiler characters, and `obufPush` is something that consumes the compiler's output.  The `record_error` is defined in the code I'm sampling from to be:

```
fun record_error {message,...} = PolyML.prettyPrint(obufPush,70) message
```